# Weird results when trying to select not 0

Tags: mysql, sql

In one of my tables I have a column which is varchar(255). The where clause looks like this

```sql
SELECT ….. WHERE ctd_ref != 0.
```

Well this works fine if the value is an integer greater than zero but does not select the entries which have `ctd_ref` value = `N8IJVW`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If it's a `varchar` try `WHERE ctd_ref != '0'` Edit: may as well put it as an answer.

Comment: Your column is a string datatype... you'll need to quote your value `'0'`

Comment: `0` is a number and you are comparing that to a varchar (also known as "comparing apples to oranges"). Compare your column to a proper string literal: `'0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast strings to zero, you get zero almost all the times, and even when you don't I don't think you get the results you want:

```
mysql> select cast('abc' as decimal), cast('' as decimal), cast('7zip' as decimal);
+------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| cast('abc' as decimal) | cast('' as decimal) | cast('7zip' as decimal) |
+------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
|                      0 |                   0 |                       7 |
+------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Just don't force such conversions, which I suspect you never intended to do:

```
SELECT … WHERE ctd_ref <> '0'
```

... and also try the opposite clause for debugging purposes:

```
SELECT … WHERE ctd_ref = '0'
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that many other DBMS will simply reject such a comparison and throw an error (a much better behavior IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a `varchar` try `WHERE ctd_ref != '0'`

If you leave it as 0, you're comparing a number to a string field, which will give you, as you say, weird results.